# Capture a header value from the response in Jmeter and re-use

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load-testing

I'm calling a REST request for authentication. And I need to get the session ID sending on response; in order to reuse that in my next request.

session id comes in **Response header**. When I use view result tree, this is not showing header parameters(response body has no data).

When googling I found a method using Regular expression Extractor method, but seems it works only when data in response body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, Regular expression extractor can search in headers also. You need to specify where to search.

See example,

[image]

This will search in headers and you can specify in main samples, sub samples also.

Comment: Hi Nachiket Kate, so if I use this, can I reuse this variable like ${id} in another(later sending) http request ?